# R data frame. How to count the number of rows addressing multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

In a data frame (patients database), I want to count the number of rows (number of patients) which address a specific condition, here the value of 3, at least one time (using the operator "or":"|"), among repeated assessments (in fact re do surgeries). This specific condition can happen one, two, three four times or more among the one, two three or more assessments. If the value of 3 is measured at least on time, the row (patient) should be count. Here is an modified extract of my data frame which has 62 columns and around 300 rows.

```
> df
    grade_chir_1 grade_chir_2 grade_chir_3 grade_d_chir
2              1          NaN            3            3
3              1          NaN          NaN          NaN
4            NaN            2          NaN          NaN
5              2          NaN          NaN          NaN
6              2            3            2            3
7              3          NaN          NaN          NaN
8              1          NaN            3          NaN
9              1          NaN          NaN          NaN
10             3            3          NaN          NaN
11             1            3            3          NaN
12             1          NaN          NaN          NaN
13             2            2          NaN          NaN
14             1          NaN          NaN          NaN
15             1            3            2            3
16             1          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

So far I only have only found this not very elegant way to do this:

> count(datam$grade_chir_1 == 3 | datam$grade_chir_2==3 | datam$grade_chir_3==3 | datam$grade_d_chir==3)[1,2]

Which give me the right number I presumed, but in a  not very nice fashion.

Any clue will be warmly welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
datam <-read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors = F, text='
       grade_chir_1 grade_chir_2 grade_chir_3 grade_d_chir
          1          NaN            3            3
          1          NaN          NaN          NaN
        NaN            2          NaN          NaN
          2          NaN          NaN          NaN
          2            3            2            3
          3          NaN          NaN          NaN
          1          NaN            3          NaN
          1          NaN          NaN          NaN
         3            3          NaN          NaN
         1            3            3          NaN
         1          NaN          NaN          NaN
         2            2          NaN          NaN
         1          NaN          NaN          NaN
         1            3            2            3
         1          NaN          NaN          NaN
        ')
datam
sum(rowSums(datam == 3, na.rm=TRUE) > 0)
[1] 7
```

Comment: +1; I think your first `na.rm` was the only one that was needed.

Comment: I think this is to complex to do with 300 rows or more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you can use `sapply` to get whether 3 is in each row, then use `sum` to count the number of rows that match that condition:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) 3 %in% df[row,])
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
sum(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) 3 %in% df[row,]))
# [1] 7
```

Comment: This seems to be one the possibility as the result is also 10.

Comment: Sorry, I use the wrong data. These doesn't work either as I get a result of 97.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of multiple OR conditions suggested this method:

```
> sum( apply(datam, 1, function(x) any(x==3) ), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 7
```

Comment: or `sum(apply(datam == 3, 1, any, na.rm = T))`, which doesn't do much different other than save the anonymous function declaration.

Comment: Good; I originally  was thinking `apply(datam, 1, any, cond)` ended up with: `eq3 <- function(x) any(x==3)
; sum( apply(datam,1,eq3), na.rm=TRUE)`, which seemed too Baroque.

Comment: With my formula I get the result of 10. With the formula of BondedDust I get 38 and with BrodieG 97 !

Comment: Post str(dataset): My guess is you have factors and are getting weird results with implicit coercion to numeric. You might check this by changing the condition to `x="3"`.

Comment: My variable are numeric see below.                                  >   str(datam)
    'data.frame':   220 obs. of  73 variables:
     $ centre                : num  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
     $ grade_chir_1          : num  1 1 NaN 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ grade_chir_2          : num  NaN NaN 2 NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
     $ grade_chir_3          : num  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
     $ grade_d_chir          : num  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...'

Answer (score 0):

Something better is:

```
table(datam$grade_chir_1 == 3 | datam$grade_chir_2==3 | datam$grade_chir_3==3 | datam$grade_d_chir==3)
TRUE 
10
```

But still not satisfactory.

also this solution:

```
sum(datam$grade_chir_1 == 3 | datam$grade_chir_2==3 | datam$grade_chir_3==3 | datam$grade_d_chir==3, na.rm=T)
[1] 10
```